# Error in FactoMineR's summary.FAMD when printing categories

Tags: r, categories, pca

I am doing a FAMD with FactoMineR treating NAs with imputeFAMD. The FAMD works fine, but the summary() produces an error just when it comes to printing the categories. There are 19 continuous and 2 categorial variables.

```
library(FactoMineR)
library(missMDA)#handle missing values
n = c(2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 3, 7, 3, 7, 8, 11, 4, 13) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb", "cc") 
b = c(1, 4, NA, NA, 2, 1, 7, 1, 2, NA, NA, 2, 1, 7, NA) 
all = data.frame(n, s, b)
complete = imputeFAMD(all)
FAMDall = FAMD(all, tab.comp = complete)
summary(FAMDall, nbelements = Inf, ncp=4)
```

after the continuous variables, the output of `summary(FAMDall, nbelements = Inf, ncp=4)` stops like this:

```
Categories
Error in mat[, indice + nb.col * (0:(ncp - 1))] <- obj$cos2[1:nbelements,  : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: Your question is not reproducible without a sample of data. Also, `imputeFAMD` is not in `library(FactoMineR)`, but in `library(missMDA)` package. Please edit your question so that it can reproduced.

Comment: just added MWE.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the `tab.comp` argument. The `FactoMineR` documentation on `?FAMD` asks for the entire object resulting from `imputeFAMD`, but what you need is the imputed matrix in the `$tab.disj` list element. See Examples section in `?imputeFAMD`. This should work:

```
n = c(2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 3, 7, 3, 7, 8, 11, 4, 13) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "bb", "cc") 
b = c(1, 4, NA, NA, 2, 1, 7, 1, 2, NA, NA, 2, 1, 7, NA) 
all = data.frame(n, s, b)
complete = imputeFAMD(all)
FAMDall = FAMD(all, tab.comp = complete$tab.disj)
summary(FAMDall, nbelements = Inf, ncp=4)
```

Comment: That's what I tried first, but the the FAMD already fails with the message `Error in tab.comp$call : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: Does `class(complete$tab.disj)` returns `matrix` for you? Do you have the latest version of `FactoMineR` and `missMDA`? If `tab.comp = complete$tab.disj` did not fix it for you, then I cannot reproduce it. The example code runs just fine for me.

Comment: yes, `> class(complete$tab.disj)` returns `[1] "matrix"` and the code in your answer produces the error above. I've got R 3.0.1 (not possible to change) and FactoMineR 1.28

Comment: I am on missMDA_1.12 and FactoMineR_1.39. While the code in the question produces an error, the code in the answer runs smoothly, so I cannot reproduce your other error on R 3.4.3.